# Share the picture directly to facebook using sharethis plugin

Tags: php

I am using ShareThis plugin and it's working perfectly. But I am building a website something close to Facebook , and it contains images.

When I share using ShareThis plugin it shares the link to the original page. But what I want is to share the picture itself directly to Facebook (like what Instagram does with Facebook).

So is there any way to do it? I am using PHP and HTML

```
<div class="sharePopup" id="shareD">
    <div class="iner">
        <span class='st_sharethis' displayText=''></span>
        <span class='st_facebook' displayText=''></span>
        <span class='st_twitter' displayText=''></span>
        <span class='st_linkedin' displayText=''></span>
        <span class='st_pinterest' displayText=''></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        <a href="#" class="facebook social-provider-icon"
                 onclick="
                window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?s=100&p[url]=' + encodeURIComponent(location.href) + '&p[images][0]=<?php echo $imageforfb; ?>&p[title]=<?php echo $ftitle; ?>',
'facebook-share-dialog',
'width=626,
height=436');
return false;">
&nbsp;
</a>
```

Comment: I'm sorry but still a newbie , where am I supposed to post this code?